# Change DIV's height via JavaScript when word-wrap occurs

Tags: php, html, css

I don't even know whether this is possible, however, I am hoping that JavaScript could provide a solution to this problem. I have a DIV, that shows the title for each page within a WordPress template that I am working on.

```
<div class="grid-block" id="page">

  <div id="page-info">

    <h3>#<?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title("",true); ?></h3>

  </div><!-- #page-info -->

</div><!-- .grid-block #page -->
```

The text that is called into the DIV comes in at various lengths, and sometimes over-exceeds the DIV. When the text exceeds the DIV, it wraps, just as it should, however, I am attempting to adjust the 'height' of this DIV, after a word is wrapped. I do not know if I could add some type of eventListener or something, however, pure HTML and/or CSS does not seem to have the components I need to solve this problem.

In addition, I understand that I 'could' use @media (media queries) to sort of emulate this effect, however, as far as I know, this can only be done in relation to the width of the Window, and I want the DIV to re-size 'only' when a string exceeds the width of this DIV. A demo of what I am attempting to do can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/SP3Q2/4/. I appreciate any comments, recommendations, and advice that anyone has regarding this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i updated the fiddle can you check now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the fix height on #page-info? If you just use padding:10, the div#page-info would automatically wrap around the text.

Comment: Although, yes, by removing the 'height' attribute from the CSS rules, the #page-info DIV would work as I am expecting, it does not when there is a DIV subsequent DIV right after. I apologize for this confusion, and I have updated my code within jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/uamUM/13/.

Comment: I see there are now two fixed height's. 80px for #page and 36px height for #page-info. I would remove them both and give the #page a margin-bottom. Or are you want to vertical align the 80px #page to another div?

Comment: Yes, the #page will be vertically aligned with another DIV, which will 'float: left', against it. However, once the page reaches a specified dimension (i.e.: smaller than 700px wide), that DIV will be placed underneath it. Everything in my actual page in stacked, one DIV on top of another, however, I am using media queries (or @media (min-width and max-width) ) to orient the DIVs beyond a certain width.

Comment: I understand, that if I omit the 'height' attribute within the CSS rules, and simply keep padding at '10px', the DIV will wrap how I wish for it to wrap, however, there is a DIV underneath, that it runs over. An example of this can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/uamUM/13/. Moreover, when the page is below 700px in width, a 'different' DIV resides underneath '#page-info', and #page-info runs over this DIV as well... after the text inside wraps. I am attempting to dynamically push the subsequent DIV (below #page-info) down, as the text wraps from within.

Comment: Ok, you can resize the other DIV with JS like this:

`$(function(){
    var pageHeight = $("#page").height();
    $("#otherDiv").height(pageHeight);
});`

And perhaps on a resize event:

`$(window).resize(function() { ... });`

Comment: An example of the #page-info DIV, running over the subsequent DIV can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/justinbyrne001/uamUM/15/.

Comment: Re-sizing the window, while using jQuery to detect when the actual '#page-info DIV' element exceeds a certain height might work. However, I am not sure whether that can be done through a conditional statement.

Comment: If you use modernizr, you could detect media queries and declare a flag variable for "responsive only" functions, exmaple: `if(Modernizr.mq('only all')) {
  flgResponsive = true;
 }`